# Oddity in ksh93 shell script ("command -p mkdir t" fails)

Tags: ksh, path, command

I have an issue with using `command -p mkdir` in a `ksh93` shell script.

The `command -p` bit is supposed to, [according to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html),

> Perform the command search using a default value for `PATH` that is guaranteed to find all of the standard utilities.

The `ksh93` manual has a similar wording:

> The `-p` option causes a default path to
>                 be searched rather than the one defined by the value of `PATH`.
>                 Functions will not be searched for when finding name.  In
>                 addition, if name refers to a special built-in, none of the
>                 special properties associated with the leading daggers will be
>                 honored.  (For example, the predefined alias `redirect='command exec'` prevents a script from terminating when an invalid
>                 redirection is given.)

I've boiled my script down to the following:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ksh93 -x
echo "$PATH"
command -p mkdir t
```

Running it:

```
$ ./test.sh
+ echo /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin
+ command -p mkdir t
./test.sh[3]: mkdir: not found [No such file or directory]
```

The default value of `$PATH` for `ksh93` (according to its manual) is `/bin:/usr/bin:`, and `mkdir` is found in `/bin`:

```
$ command -v mkdir
/bin/mkdir
```

If I issue the `getconf PATH` command in the script (to get the value of the default system-defined `$PATH`), before calling `mkdir`, *the call to `mkdir` succeeds*.

This is seen in `ksh93`, "Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01", on at least Ubuntu, OpenBSD, macOS and Solaris, and also affect at least `cat` when invoked the same way.

**The question:** Did I miss something obvious here?

**Additional info:**

The `builtin` command in `ksh93` lists a number of utilities under the (non-existent) path `/opt/ast/bin`. Does this have something to do with this?

```
$ builtin
:
.
[
/opt/ast/bin/basename
/opt/ast/bin/cat
/opt/ast/bin/chmod
/opt/ast/bin/cmp
/opt/ast/bin/cut
/opt/ast/bin/dirname
/opt/ast/bin/getconf
/opt/ast/bin/head
/opt/ast/bin/logname
/opt/ast/bin/mkdir
/opt/ast/bin/sync
/opt/ast/bin/uname
/opt/ast/bin/wc
alarm
alias
```

(etc.)

UPDATE: I have submitted this query to the `ast-users` mailing list as well.

Comment: Huh. It works from an interactive shell session, but not a `#!ksh93` script.

Comment: Hint: The question is not quoting the ksh93 manual when it quotes an explanation of the `-p` option.

Comment: @JdeBP So? The ksh93 manual states “The -p option causes a default path to be searched rather than the one defined by the value of PATH”, which is reasonably close. And ksh93 does strive to be POSIX-compliant. This smells like a bug.

Comment: "Reasonably close" is not "the same".  Another hint: This is not the manual's only mention of default paths.

Comment: @JdeBP You are absolutely right, the "default path" is `/bin:/usr/bin:` according to the `ksh93` manual. Any more hints?

Comment: I see in my ksh man page (93u+) this: "The default path is equal to getconf PATH output", so what is the output of `getconf PATH` command?

Comment: @glennjackman I can't find that in my manual, but it is the same path as displayed by my test script in the question, `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin`. My manual says "The default path is `/bin:/usr/bin:`", but it doesn't matter since `/bin` is in both paths.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you've shown here and on `ast-user`, this looks like a bug, but this is not an answer to that question.

## Re Builtin

This might better be answered in a separate question, but for now this must suffice:

Ksh93 has a feature where additional commands can be loaded from shared libraries, and then bound to an existing (or non-existing) directory in `$PATH`

The commands with the `/opt/ast/bin/` path are considered to be *bound* to `/opt/ast/bin`.  That means that if a $PATH has `/opt/bin/ast/bin` *before* `/bin`, ksh93 will invoke the builtin `cat` in preference over `/bin/cat`.

Whether `/opt/ast/bin` or `/opt/ast/bin/cat` exist or not does not have any effect on this mechanism.

Comment: Ah, that explains the mysterious paths. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`command -p` is known to be very buggy in AT&T release versions of ksh93 because the default/standard path is not initialised properly. This is one of the many hundreds of bugs fixed in [ksh 93u+m](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh) which is under active maintenance and development (I'm the main dev/maintainer). It is currently the default ksh93 in at least Debian unstable and Slackware-current, but of course you can also get the code and compile your own.